# flyway commandline, How to log the messages in a log file during migration

Tags: log4j, flyway

This question is regarding the "logging the messages in a log file, while migrating through flyway command line". I went through the below links in StackOverflow, and followed the steps mentioned, but couldn't get the list of steps to follow to see the messages in log file.

[How configure logging for Flyway command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41106265/how-configure-logging-for-flyway-command-line)

[Flyway logging with log4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22356381/flyway-logging-with-log4j)

[Flyway logging with Logback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25597716/flyway-logging-with-logback?rq=1)

I have placed log4j-1.2.17.jar, logback-classic-1.1.7.jar, logback-core-1.1.7.jar and slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar under flyway/lib folder and placed the logback.xml in conf location (also tried moving out of conf location too).
Lib is mentioned in the classpath in flyway and flyway.cmd files.

But I always see the debug messages on stdout, and no log file is being created.

Flyway version 4.2.0

Could someone share the list of steps, to write the log messages on a log file during migration/info.

Answer (score 0):

While keeping logback.xml inside conf directory, You need to edit flyway/flyway.cmd based on your environment.

Replace line `CP="$INSTALLDIR/lib/*:$INSTALLDIR/drivers/*"`

with

`CP="$INSTALLDIR/conf:$INSTALLDIR/lib/*:$INSTALLDIR/drivers/*"`

Replace line

`%JAVA_CMD% -cp "%INSTALLDIR%\lib\*;%INSTALLDIR%\drivers\*" org.flywaydb.commandline.Main %*`

with

`%JAVA_CMD% -cp "%INSTALLDIR%\conf:%INSTALLDIR%\lib\*;%INSTALLDIR%\drivers\*" org.flywaydb.commandline.Main %*`

**Explanation:**
conf directory is not declared as classpath in the execution scripts. So need to add it in classpath so that logback.xml can be read from classpath.
anywhere you put the logback.xml file, it has to be declared as classpath.

Comment: Thanks for your response Mhshimul. Missed to specify in the original post that logback.xml path is included in the classpath, in flyway.cmd file. Even after including the conf location in flyway.cmd file still do not see a log file generated (have created a logs directory manually).